# Azure AD Integration Between Portals

Tags: active-directory, entra-id, azure-networking, microsoft

This may be a crazy question, but I am trying to find out if this is possible.  Here is the situation:

We are Office 365 customers, with local AD and Exchange that sync to EOL/Azure AD in a hybrid environment.  We are implementing a new EHR that will feature AD integration.  They want to set up a VPN tunnel and connect to our local AD for this, but they are hosted in Azure, and use Azure AD also, and I am wondering if there is some way to establish some sort of portal to portal connection where they could access our Azure AD that way.

I know there is app integration in Azure, but I would not be able to do it that way with this application.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to have some sort of trust between the tenants, then nope this is not available: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/20478244-allow-azure-ad-to-azure-ad-trust

The closest you can get is B2B access, as in have one of their users invited to your tenant to access resources, you can control their access using RBAC: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/what-is-b2b

Perhaps this could be explored for more options? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/plan-cloud-hr-provision